# Satellite Image Mosaicing Memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, gis, heap-memory, large-data

I want to mosaic satellite images obtained from http://landsatlook.usgs.gov/ . But these images  are very large about 8000*8000 pixel. when I want to mosaic four images I get java heap space error. I increased jvm heap space (-Xmx -Xms) but as increase number of images, I get same error. Performance is not very important for me without getting the same (out of memory).

How to solve the memory problem?

Comment: As a first step, I would suggest to allocate all memory you got (except 10% to leave someting for your OS). How much memory does you system have ? When it works I would monitor the needed memory to get an idea of how much memory is required

Comment: As a second step I aould look into the details of the image format you use an try to reduce the memory needed for every color cahnnel, like some formats use 32bit per color channel, where 8bit would be sufficient

Comment: Memory is 6gb. I allocate 4gb (-Xmx4g) for my app but need more  memory. I must not change original image format. Number of images can increase more for example 20 images so I dont want to depend memory too much.